# My ASUS 1005HA will not turn on

Tags: troubleshooting, power-supply

My Asus EEE PC 1005H refused to turn on this morning. No lights went on, and there's nothing on the display, it seems completely dead.

It worked alright yesterday but I noticed this morning nothing worked at all - I've tried removing the battery and the pressing the start button repeatedly. Is there any way I can fix this?

I also noticed some water stains and I assume that I spilled some water on it while having a drink.

Please help me as I did not back up my work and I need to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather certain there isn't that much you can do if its water damage but you should be able to remove the hard drive and get data off it that way. Unlike older pata drives, newer laptop drives use the same connectors as regular ones, so if there's *any* way to get data off that system, it would be by removing the hard drive, mounting it to another system or USB interface and praying that it works. This may void the warranty, but water damage would do that too.

Comment: It [looks like](http://netbooked.net/images/uploads/articles/1005pr-in.jpg) the 1005H has a standard 2.5" SATA hard drive, there appears to be a guide linked from [here](http://www.myasuseee.com/how-to-dissect-the-asus-eee-pc-1005ha) about dissecting it, but the website (http://forum.eeeuser.com/) is currently down for maintenance.